# Highlight appearing elements

Tags: r, ggplot2, gif, animated-gif, gganimate

Not sure if there is a function that possibly highlights the element(border) that is appearing, let's say in red, and then has it change to a different color like black in the subsequent frames. Would be great to also show how to change the size of the border.

Example:

```
# load packages 
pack <- c('gganimate','rnaturalearth','sf','tidyverse')
lapply(pack,require,character.only=T)

# create the gif for African content
africa <- ne_countries(continent = "africa",returnclass ="sf")
# get 10 countries
country10 <- st_as_sf(head(africa, 10))
# set the factor level for the apperance order of the countries
country10$order <- factor(country10$sovereignt,levels=country10$sovereignt)

#  merge geometry for africa
africa$un <- rep.int(1,length(africa$featurecla))
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
africa <- africa %>%
  group_by(un) %>%
  summarise(geometry=st_union(geometry))


a <- ggplot(data = africa) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  coord_sf()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey", colour = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey",colour = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  geom_sf(data = country10, col = "black", fill = "transparent") +
  transition_states(order) + shadow_mark()

# output Africa gif
animate(a,fps=10, height = 4,
        width = 3, units = "cm", res = 600)
anim_save("africa.gif")
```

[image: highlight appearing element(border in this case)])

Comment: What about first drawing it in red (`col = "red"`) then overdraw it again in black?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on comments --

If you assign an "age" to each country object, then each time thru your plotting loop you can compare the "age" against the loop counter and select the color based on that difference.   I think this will require a minor rewrite of your code so that you don't include  all the elements of  `country10` in a given call to `geom_sf` .  Update your `grob` in a loop, adding one country at a time.

Comment: Indeed, just curious if there is a package such as `gganimate` can also do that